# Minimal setup to output 30V through GPIO

Tags: gpio, power-supply, output

I have a bell that works with a coil and when I put 30V (or more) on the coil the bell rings once. So now I want to be able to control that bell using my Raspi.

I have a USB Charger for powering my Raspberry Pi which outputs 5V DC 1200 mA.

I don't want to have another power supply if possible and I now need to somehow transform the 5 Volts to 30 Volts while being able to switch it on and off using the GPIO.

The coil says it's 300 Ohms and can handle 7000 Watts.

This is the actual bell:

[image]

Comment: You want to use the 5V 1200 mA Pi supply.  Assuming the Pi uses 500 mA there will be 5x0.7 or 3.5 Watts available.  Assuming 80% efficiency once converted to 30V there will be 2.8 Watts for the bell.  Will that be enough to make it ring?

Comment: @joan If I apply the 30 volts to the 300 Ohm coil it really just needs a split second in order to ring. So it requires 3 Watts for a short period of time. The question for me is, how can I produce the 30 Volts without another power supply.

Comment: Google boost converter, or go to eBay and enter boost converter.

Comment: @joan: Thanks for the comment. I found a boost converter. http://www.dx.com/p/lm2587-high-power-dc-dc-3-5-30v-boost-converter-module-green-155170#.U7ZqkhaHmuc. I will try this out and post any results here

Comment: For the switching a chip such as a ULN2003A is reasonably straightforward and will work from the Pi's 3.3V gpios and has flyback protection.  You may prefer to use discrete logic, i.e. transistors, diodes, resistors.

Comment: Good point. So I won't be able to just connect the input of the boost converter to the output of the GPIO?

Comment: No, the 3V3 rail at most can only supply of the order of 50mA.  It's suggested that you don't try to draw more than 16mA from any one gpio.  Probably simplest to always have the boost converter input powered from the 5V rail (pins P1-2/P1-4) but have the 30V switched by the ULN2003A or similar.

Comment: An example of using the ULN2803 as mentioned by @joan is [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-10-stepper-motors)

Comment: I'd also add a large capacitor. Suddenly drawing 3W of power could make the 5v dip a little. The Pi is quite sensitive to this.

Comment: The main issue in trying to use this power source you have is the minimum power needed for the coil to work. As @Winkleink's answer points out below: it smells like your power source will just not be enough. If you have access to a controllable power source, check out what is the amperage needed at 30V to make it work. The minimum amperage.

Comment: If you just want 1 power source. Get a 30Volt 25Watt power adapter and convert that to 5v for the Pi and leave the rest for the bell. Simple. PS. Can you take a clear picture of the wiring diagram. Maybe its abtually 110vac input?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using a 5V 1200mA PSU to power the Pi and the Bell will not be enough power.
The bell looks old school electroncs and from the size of components will draw a lot more than 6 Watts which is the total output from your PSU.

Do you know what the minimum wattage needed is to make the bell work.
Is it 7000 Watts?
Is so then at 5V assuming 100% efficient you you have to have 1400A PSU a bit different to your current 6A PSU.

So, you will definitely need a different power supply for the bell.
Then it is a matter of tripping a relay from the Pi to activate the bell.

Most relays require 5V signal to operate then and as the Raspberry Pi outputs 3.3V a little extra assistance is needed to make this work.

The following post explains it very well.
http://www.openhomeautomation.net/control-a-relay-from-anywhere-using-the-raspberry-pi/

**Summary:**
You can't power the bell from the PSU you have
Use a Relay
Need a circuit to step up the 3.3V GPIO signal to 5V to activate the relay.